# Why collector current is inwards to transistor in an NPN?

Tags: transistors, current

In [this](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/transistor/tran_1.htmlhttp://) page, the following model is given for an NPN BJT.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f49hoo.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Also, it is stated that I(e) is outwards from the transistor, I(b) is inwards to the transistor and I(c) is inwards to the transistor as well.

But according to this diagram, isn't I(c) supposed to be outwards from the transistor? How can it be inwards to the transistor? Could you explain this?

Comment: normally +Vcc is connected to the collector and the emitter is connected to the ground. the base is also at higher potential than the ground. the base-emitter junction is forward biased so when certain amount of base current flows to the emitter the depletion region becomes very narrow and the dynamic resistance between collector and emitter terminals drops dramatically which allows a current from +Vcc to ground. collector current now flows into the transistor and then to the ground together with the base current.

Comment: The two-diode model of a transistor is inaccurate and misleading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a multimeter and satisfy yourself of the existence of two diodes inside an NPN transistor but that doesn't mean it makes sense to imagine that a BJT relies on that fact for its operation.

The collector-base region IS reverse biased and the diode shown in the question IS therefore shown correctly. Also, just because the collector-base is reverse biased doesn't mean that no current can flow. Study the BJT and you will (eventually) understand that electrons are carried across the base into the collector region **because** the reverse bias IS present: -

[image]

A BJT isn't just two diodes built inside one package.

Comment: In fact, if you study it from a device mechanics point, you will eventually understand that electrons/holes are carried between the base and collector **because** the reverse bias is present.

Comment: @Dave yes you put that better than me in my 2nd paragraph so I shall steal your words!!

Answer (score 0):

A very simple explanation. When current flows from the base to the emitter the collector diode is replaced by a resistor and allows current to flow inwards from collector to emitter. The higher the base-emitter current then the lower the value of the resistor. A very small base-emitter current can control much larger collector-emitter current. For example a 1mA base-emitter current may control 100mA collector-emitter current, this would be a current gain of 100.